# Custom ConfigSection either to load it from app.config or from external file

Tags: c#, configuration, configsection

We have specific need for Custom configuration in app.config which I have successfully implemented but in case if that section is exponentially increasing which may occur as more and more functionality adding to our application, I want to separate the ConfigSection into separate file and provide the feasibility to load configuration either from Custom ConfigSection or external config file. I want to provide both options so later application admin can choose which way they want upon need. I looked all around internet but nothing found of my interest. First I would like to know if at all is it possible and if so some short example will help me lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `ConfigSections` and put it right in `app.config`.

Or, if you want, you can put your custom confic section into a separated file and put the path to this file in your `app.config` file (see below).

```
<appSettings configSource="appSettings.config" />
<connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config"/>
<pages configSource="pages.config"/>
```

For more info see this page which will help you decide if a configuration section can be stored externally:

[General Attributes Inherited by Section Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228167(v=vs.100).aspx)